# Почему не работает import из соседней папки?

Tags: python, импорт, path

[image]

Имеется, значит, вот такая директория. А главный герой в ней - моя попытка в юнит тесты "test_clien.py".
Код в нем выглядит следующим образом:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('D:/Python/Projects/Client-server applications/My_messenger/common')
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..'))

from common.vars import PORT

a = PORT
print(a)
```

Как вы видите, я подсмотрел пару приемчиков, но все безуспешно. Итог один:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Python\Projects\Client-server applications\My_messenger\unit_tests\test_client.py", line 6, in 
> from common.vars import PORT
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'

Работает вот такой трюк:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)
```

И его простая версия:

```
sys.path.append('../') #добавить директорию на уровень выше    
from common.vars import PORT
```

[image]

Но PyCharm крайне недоволен.

Comment: `from ..common.vars import PORT` попробуйте

Comment: @Namerek Пробовал: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". . [Здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/guide-into-python-imports/#4) вычитал что такое поддерживает только Python 2. На данный момент я вижу только одно решение: создать копию моих переменных внутри папки с тестами. Временно этим костылем и воспользуюсь, но очень надеюсь, что есть разумное решение этой задачи.

Comment: Я бы тесты вынес из пакета My_messenger (т.к. тесты запускаются отдельно, а не как часть пакета, да и в боевом окружении только боевой код нужен по сути), а дальше в тестах импортировал как `from My_messenger.common.vars import PORT`

Comment: Никакие трюки не нужны, просто вытащите тесты из общего пакета.

Comment: @insolor По сути - согласен. Но вопрос заключается не в том, как заставить все работать, а как расположить тесты элегантно: в моем видении проекта хотелось бы выделить тесты в отдельную папку, но где бы эта папка не находилась для доступа в код всегда придется делать шаг в родительскую директорию. Да и как вы видите вынесение тестов за директорию мессенджера? В папке "Python" папки "Messenger", "Learning", "Alghoritms","New_idea" и мешанина из тестов для каждого проекта? Или может стоит создать внутри "Messenger" папку main и в нее поместить все, помимо тестов?

Comment: `Или может стоит создать внутри "Messenger" папку main и в нее поместить все, помимо тестов?` - обычно в папке проекта делают папку с названием проекта (пакет), рядом папку с тестами, еще папку с документацией, и т.д. Снаружи всякие служебные файлы типа setup.py, pyproject.toml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import os 
import sys
sys.path.append('../') #добавить директорию на уровень выше    
from common.vars import PORT

a = PORT
print(a)
```

Если хотите чтобы pycharm не ругался, то нужно в настройках изменить source root. Вот инструкция: https://russianblogs.com/article/16851293930/
Но лично я всегда забиваю на это, так как понимаю что это важно лишь в случае ананкастного расстройства личности разработчика :)

Comment: Окей, спасибо, это работает. Но PyCharm ругается, а это крайне мозолит глаза:

Unresolved reference 'common' &
Unresolved reference 'PORT'

Comment: @Crasow, написал дополнение к ответу для вашей проблемы. Если я вам помог, то нажмите стрелочку вверх у моего ответа или галочку (а лучше и то и другое), это намного лучше чем сказать "Спасибо" :)